# Where is the Spark home directory?

Tags: software-installation, directory

I followed the official installation guide and installed spark on my Ubuntu 15 system.

I can run `.bin/pyspark` without any problem. But if I want to write a `.py` script and put it somewhere, so that I can use `pyspark-submit` method to run this script, I don't know where my spark is installed.

How can I find out which folder is my spark home directory?

Comment: Try typing `source /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` and see if `$SPARK_HOME` is defined

Comment: Thanks! But it turned out to be "No such file or directory" error. And I did `cd` to `/etc` folder and could not see `/spark` sub-folder. It's so strange...